# How to prevent the ActionBar Menu from collapsing on selection?

Tags: android, checkbox, menu

Here is my menu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<item
   android:id="@+id/filter"
    android:icon="@drawable/filter"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="Filter">

    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_dropdown1"
            android:title="free"
            android:checkable="true"
            app:showAsAction="always"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_free"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_dropdown2"
            android:title="paid"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_paid">

            <menu>
                <group android:checkableBehavior="all">

                <item
                    android:id="@+id/paid_cat1"
                    android:title="0-50"
                    android:checkable="true"
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_paid"/>
                <item
                    android:checkable="true"
                    android:id="@+id/paid_cat2"
                    android:title="51-100"
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_paid"/>

                <item
                    android:checkable="true"
                    android:id="@+id/paid_cat3"
                    android:title="101-500"
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_paid"/>

                <item
                    android:checkable="true"
                    android:id="@+id/paid_cat4"
                    android:title="500-10,000"
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_paid"/>

                <item
                    android:checkable="true"
                    android:id="@+id/paid_cat5"
                    android:title="show all"
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_paid"/>

                </group>

            </menu>
            </item>

        <item

            android:id="@+id/action_find"
            android:title="find"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_black_24dp"/>

    </menu>
    </item>

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    android:title="Search"/>
```

What i want to achieve is user should be able to select multiple menu items when when they click on checkbox in menu ... but i as soon as click item it disappear

or is there any better alternative to achieve the same i thought of using spinner as well but it behaves the same

Answer (score 2):

You can use popup menu with custom layout anchored to the menu item.
Show the popup menu when "paid" menu item is clicked -

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_dropdown2:
            showPopUp();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

public void showPopUp() {
    View mPopUpView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.checkable_items, null);
     PopupWindow mPopupWindow = new PopupWindow(
            mPopUpView,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    mPopupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);
    mPopupWindow.setFocusable(true);
    mPopupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable());
    // Set content width and height
    mPopupWindow.setHeight(convertDpToPx(140));
    mPopupWindow.setWidth(convertDpToPx(120));
    mPopupWindow.showAsDropDown(this.findViewById(R.id.filter), convertDpToPx(-20), convertDpToPx(-40));
}

int convertDpToPx(int dp){
    return   (int) (dp * Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().density);
}
```

This is the custom layout checkable_items.xml -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/white"
android:orientation="vertical">

<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="0-50" />

<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="51-100" />

<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="101-500" />

<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="500-10,000" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Update the menu file to -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<item
    android:id="@+id/filter"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"
    android:title="Filter"
    app:showAsAction="always">

    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_dropdown1"
            android:checkable="true"
            android:icon="@android:drawable/btn_dialog"
            android:title="free"
            app:showAsAction="always" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_dropdown2"
            android:icon="@android:drawable/btn_minus"
            android:title="paid">

        </item>

        <item

            android:id="@+id/action_find"
            android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"
            android:title="find" />

    </menu>
</item>

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
    android:title="Search"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

You can use mPopupWindow.dismiss() to close the popup anytime.Hope this helps!

[image]

Comment: Its working but icons are not visible in popup window as they are visible in menu

Comment: its doning the trick but thing is in popwindow icons are not visible and basically what we are doing here is when menu dismiss we are showing popwindow and it looks completely different is there anyway to prevent menu from getting dismiss . Any help would be appreated

Comment: in popwindow icons are not visible - its a custom layout..so you can add icons to the left and move the checkbox to right to make it look exactly how you want.

Comment: when menu dismiss we are showing popwindow and it looks completely different - wasn't it looking the same when you clicked on "paid" earlier? It closes the menu and opens the submenu.

Comment: it does the job . but when i click on item for popwindow it dismiss on click as menu doesnt allow me for multiple selection . how to fix that?

Comment: If you click on multiple items..it still wont dismiss until mPopupWindow.dismiss() is called.